# Is it correct to combine losses from different layers in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient

Is it possible to combine the loss from different layers?
Say I have one model with five layers.

The first loss (whatever it may be) is computed from the outputs of the third layer with some labels.

The second loss (say, your typical cross-entropy loss) is computed from the outputs of the last layer with your classification labels.

An example with codes is as below:

```
def get_intermediate_model(base_model, intermediate_layer):
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=base_model.layers[intermediate_layer-1].output)
    return model

def gradientCalculation(fullModel, inputData, intermediateLabels,labels):
    intermediateModel = get_intermediate_model(fullModel,3)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        intermediateOutput = intermediateModel(inputData,training=True)
        classifierOutput = fullModel(inputData,training=True)

        intermediate_layer_loss = anyLossFunction(intermediateLabels,intermediateOutput)
        classifier_loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(classifierOutput,labels)
        
        combinedFinalLoss = classifier_loss + (0.2 * intermediate_layer_loss )

    gradients = tape.gradient(combinedFinalLoss , fullModel.trainable_variables)
    return gradients
```

as you can see, the gradient is generated from the summed loss with the `fullModel` rather than from `intermediateModel`.

Is this sort of operation correct? Can `tf.GradientTape()` keep track of the loss that was computed from the intermediate layers and can compute the gradient accordingly?

Or are we just adding more losses that the entire model is optimizing?

(The desired results would be the first 3 layers of the fullModel would receive 2 gradients summed together, one gradient from the 1st loss that has been reduced with a coefficient (0.2) and the 2nd from the
backpropagation due to the cross entropy loss for all the layers. The 4th and 5th layer only receives gradients from the cross entropy loss)

Comment: `GradientTape` can handle addition and multiplication, it will compute the gradient accordingly. And since the derivative of a sum equals the sum of the derivatives, I think the result will be your desired results (if I understand them correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `tf.GradientTape()` keeps indeed track of the several losses and will compute the gradient accordingly.

There is a problem in your code because the same data goes twice through the network:

```
intermediateOutput = intermediateModel(inputData,training=True)
classifierOutput = fullModel(inputData,training=True)
```

From the computational point view it is wrong.
You could define a single model that outputs both tensors :

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=[base_model.layers[intermediate_layer-1].output, base_model.output])
```

Note that you only need to set `tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)` if you call `tape.gradient` multiple times (in GANs for instance).

Comment: Thank you for the answer
I'm aware that you can call the gradient twice and manipulate two gradients from there, but from my experience, setting persistent=True would significantly make the training slower.
So I thought if I could do it in one pass with one gradient for optimal training time.

Thank you for the tips on the model outputting 2 performances :)